# (In R shiny) About upload multiple csv files and print all tables out

Tags: r, file, input, shiny

I want to upload two csv files and print both tables out.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "files", label = "Choose CSV File", multiple = TRUE,accept = c(".csv")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(tableOutput("Policy1")),
      fluidRow(tableOutput("Policy2")),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactiveValues(file1 = NULL,
                         file2 = NULL)
                        
 
  output$Policy1 <- renderTable({
    if(!is.null(input$files$datapath[1])) 
    data$file1 <- read.csv(input$files$datapath[1], header = TRUE)
    data$file1
  })
  output$Policy2 <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(input$files$datapath[2])) {return(1)}
    else{return(NULL)}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and for the `output$Policy2` part, I want to test when the `is.null(input$files$datapath[2])` is true. I thought it should be true when I only upload one file or don't upload anything but
[image]

if I only upload one csv file, it didn't print out the table 1, which means `is.null(input$files$datapath[2])` is false in this case.I don't know why this is the case.
And as a result, if I change the code to ask shiny print two tables for me and only upload one file, there will be an error, here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "files", label = "Choose CSV File", multiple = TRUE,accept = c(".csv")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(tableOutput("Policy1")),
      fluidRow(tableOutput("Policy2")),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactiveValues(file1 = NULL,
                         file2 = NULL)
                        
 
  output$Policy1 <- renderTable({
    if(!is.null(input$files$datapath[1])) 
    data$file1 <- read.csv(input$files$datapath[1], header = TRUE)
    data$file1
  })
  output$Policy2 <- renderTable({
    if(!is.null(input$files$datapath[2])) 
      data$file2 <- read.csv(input$files$datapath[2], header = TRUE)
    data$file2
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

where I only change a little part and here is the error :
[image]

which I assume is because I should return NULL when only one file inputed in, how can I fix this problem, thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value won't be NULL if it's missing. It's better to check that there are enough values checking the length of the vector or something. For example

```
  output$Policy2 <- renderTable({
    if(!is.null(input$files) && length(input$files$datapath)>=2) 
      data$file2 <- read.csv(input$files$datapath[2], header = TRUE)
    data$file2
  })
```